# If you change the destination URL of a goal, will you lose historical data?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm redoing a previously static HTML site into WordPress. The existing site has 3 goals setup as destination goals to thank you pages that come up after a form is submitted (foo.html, bar.html, foobar.html). Once the new site launches, the new thank you page URLs will be different (/foo/, /bar/, /foobar/). If I go in and change the destination URLs of the goals - will I lose any historical data associated with them? If so, am I better off just creating new goals for the 3 thank you pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you change or repurpose an existing goal, be sure to keep track of when you made the change. Since goals are not applied to historical data, changing a goal will change your conversion data from the point of the change. This might lead to confusion in your reports. (This is another reason to name your goals intuitively).

Comment: So I will not lose the historical data?

Comment: No you won't new hits won't be counted as goal reached in the new way that's all